# Git pull after git commit

Tags: git, github

I have a simple app with two developers, I have finished my task, here is what I have done

```
git add.
git commit -m 'my task'
```

Now when I check the repo on GitHub I see there are new changes from another developer,

So what do I need to do to have new changes in my local machine and merge with my changes?,

Comment: uhm ? `git pull origin master`, `git push origin master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey that's really simple.

You have to PULL the changes from the remote branch.

```
git pull origin master
```

change master to the branch you wish to pull from

checkout https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull